# Proof about the theorem of checking whether a subset of a set is open.

Tags: general-topology

I am having some trouble proving the converse and also not quite sure if the proof below is correct.

Statement:A set $U$ is open in a topological space (X,T) if and only if for every point $x \in U$. there exists an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x \subset U$.

Proof:Being open means a set is part of the collection $T$. So if there exists in $T$ sets that include each of the elements of $U$  (if they are open), by 4) $U$ is forced to be open.

$4)$ comes from this:

Suppose $X$ is a set. Then $T$ is a topology on $X$ if and only if $T$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that

1. $\phi \in T$
2. $X \in T$
3. $\text{if } U \in T \text{and } V \in T, \text{then } U \cap V \in T, \text{and} $
4. $\text{if} \{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \lambda} \text{is any collection of sets of T, then } \bigcup_{\alpha \in \lambda}U_\alpha \in T$

Anyways, I don't know how I would prove "if $U$ is open then for every point $x \in U$. there exists an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x \subset U$".

Comment: Take $U_x=U$. QED.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks!